# Is it possible if I want to change my docker data-root directory to another server?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, winscp

I installed docker inside of a server or what I usually called as a VM (Virtual Machine, with RHEL environment) and I have been thinking of using a new directory in a remoted Windows network as my new data-root directory (due to space reason).

In my case, the [data-root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8hjr.png) from my VM located at /home/docker_new and the path where I want to use as a new data-root directory from the remote Windows network is for example, at
\\xx.xx.x.x\a\b\c.

I did try to make my research and finds that most of the solutions are all focusing on **changing the data-root directory within the same VM**. Some focusing on **how to 'move' the docker to another server**. While what I intended to do is just to change the data-root directory to another directory in a remoted windows network .

So, my question is:

```
1. Is it possible to do so?
2. If its possible, what are the steps that I should follow?
```